# Plot 2 curves on one subplot, one curve's x axis starts at the largest x value of the other curve (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to do the following with python (matplotlib):

I have 2 curves on 2 subplots. I want both curves on the same subplot. Curve A:

[image: Curve A]

And curve B:

[image: curve B]

Here is what I want...Curve B to be on the same subplot as curve A. Curve B's x axis to start on right right side of curve A (Curve B's x=0 should be located at Curve A's highest x value (around 0.62) and curve B's x axis should increase going to the left.

Then I want to omit curve B's axis ticks and labels (so there is one set of ticks and labels for the entire subplot).

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why can't you just concatenate the x and y axis of curve B to curve A, then plot that?  If you post some sample data I'm sure we could help.

Comment: Because the X axes are different. The x axis of curve A is Charge Capacity (Ah) while for B it's Discharge Capacity (Ah)

Comment: So you want your x axis to go from 0 - 0.62, jump to 0 and then go back up to 0.6?  Just plot two subplots side-by-side, and adjust the ticks to suit...

Comment: @JodyKlymak No I want them both on a single subplot